# create mysql query for fetching data in 3 days slotwise

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to create a query for fetch all the data from database. But condition is get from before current month and data will convert into 3 days slot wise with count.Like if i have 12 month data and in July 1 to 3 date data will insert into 50 rows and from 3 to 6 date data will insert into 5 rows.How i fetch this things.That is the mail problem. I have wondered but nothing found related my problem. Is this possible.

Comment: I don't understand the problem exactly. Now in August 2014 you want the data of July 2014 with the count of rows per 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, ... 28-30 and the 31th of July? Is that right?

Comment: yes in 3 days slot wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a DATE or a DATETIME column, that marks the day of the insert, say the column `created_at`. Then you could get the desired result.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    (DAYOFMONTH(created_at) - 1) DIV 3
```

**Explanation:**

With the help of the [DIV](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) operator you get your 3-day-slots.

**Note**
If there's a slot without rows, it won't be in the result. To get these too, you could use a LEFT JOIN with the maximum  11 slots.

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f0fc/7)**

Answer (score 0):

If you having timestamps as attribute type then might be this help you

```
SELECT count(*) as count
        FROM table
        AND
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,date,2014-08-01)<=3";
```

The date is the attribute of your column, **TIMESTAMPDIFF** will find difference between given date if it's under 3 days from 2014-08-01 records will show up. This way by just sending one date into this position you can find 3 slots of date from your table.